# creating a username with no spaces with PHP function ..but somehow spaces are being added?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that generates a username based on when someone logs in via Facebook.

I am calling it like this:

```
$username = create_username($facebook_data['name']);
```

And the function is:

```
function create_username($username)
{
global $db;

$valid = false;
$counter = 0;
$new_username = str_replace(' ', '', $username);

while (!$valid) 
{
    $counter++;
    $is_username = $db->count_rows('users', "WHERE username='" . $new_username . "'");

    if ($is_username)
    {
        $new_username = $username . $counter;
    }
    else 
    {
        $valid = true;
    }
}

$new_username = strtolower($new_username);
return $new_username;
```

}

The problem is, if I have a user that is called "johnsmith" and someone with the name of "john smith" registers, it generates a username that is "john smith1" instead of "johnsmith1". What am I doing wrong?

I even did a

```
var_dump($facebook_data['name'])
```

and it is returned as "John Smith", with no extra spaces or anything.

Comment: `$new_username = $username = str_replace(' ', '', $username);`

Comment: Just change to `$username = str_replace(' ', '', $username);` and `$is_username = $db->count_rows('users', "WHERE username='" . $username . "'");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are using the `$username` variable in your loop so you will get a username with spaces if the original username already exists.

Below I've created a `$clean_username` variable that can be appended to so you get `username6` instead of `username123456` for example:

```
function create_username($username)
{
   global $db;

   $valid = false;
   $counter = 0;
   $clean_username = $new_username = str_replace(' ', '', $username);

   while (!$valid) 
   {
       $counter++;
       $is_username = $db->count_rows('users', "WHERE username='" . $new_username . "'");

       if ($is_username)
       {
           $new_username = $clean_username . $counter;
       }  
       else 
       {
           $valid = true;
       }
   }

   $new_username = strtolower($new_username);
   return $new_username;
}
```

Comment: Check comments maybe can help to improve your answer

Comment: That worked perfectly. I will accept your answer in a few minutes when I can. Thank you! :)

Comment: FYI @Mark-Baker's comment will do the job too, I just prefer to leave my function parameters untouched which is why I made the `$clean_username` variable. Chacun son goût!

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($is_username)
{
    $new_username = $username . $counter;
}
```

correct is

```
if ($is_username)
{
    $new_username = $new_username . $counter;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, so first concatenation will give `username1`, if that's taken, second check will be `username12`, third iteration will give `username123`, fourth gives `username1234`, etc

Comment: Yes, that's what I noticed too ...it generates username12 instead of username1. It almost worked but not quite, sorry! :(